# С помощью чего можно реализовать прямую передачу данных с одного WIFI модуля ESP на другой?

Tags: wifi, arduino, esp8266

Всем привет. Необходимо напрямую общаться между двумя модулями ESP12 без роутера, на одном из модулей висит датчик. Данные с этого датчика необходимо принимать другим ESP модулем и выводить в серийный порт. Получилось сделать это на TKDClient, но скорость передачи очень низкая, если ставлю delay<1000, то вообще ничего не приходит. Наслышан что существуют протоколы Socket, TCP/IP, UDP. Как их можно реализовать? Писал в Arduino IDE!

```
void loop()
{
GetAccelerometerReadings(accResult); //считываем данные с акселерометра
GetGyroscopeReadings(gyroResult); //считываем данные с гироскопа
TKDClient.print(accResult[0]); //AccX
TKDClient.print('\t');
TKDClient.print(accResult[1]); //AccY
TKDClient.print('\t');
TKDClient.print(accResult[2]); //AccZ
TKDClient.print('\n');
delay(1000);
TKDClient.flush();
}
```

[image: Скриншот полученных данных с частотой в 1 секунду. Такая скорость не устраивает.]

Comment: У ESP8266 максимальная скорость передачи данных составляет 19200 бод.

Answer (score 1):

UDP позволяет передать данные с акселерометра с довольно быстрой скоростью т.к. данный протокол позволяет отправлять данные только в одном направлении не дожидаясь подтверждение. В своем примере я получаю данные по трем осям и температуры примерно с частотой примерно 10 раз в секунду.

Ниже выписка из моих кодов

На стороне акселерометра (передатчика):

В "шапке"

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

const char* ssid = "Serv1";
const char* password = "";
//Wi-Fi
WiFiUDP Udp;
IPAddress apIP(192,168,0,10);
unsigned int localUdpPort = 4210;  // local port to listen on
char incomingPacket[5];  // buffer for incoming packets
char  sendX[] = "X = ";  // a reply string X to send back
char  sendY[] = "Y = ";  // a reply string Y to send back
char  sendT[] = "T = ";  // a reply string T to send back
char  sendB[] = "B = ";  // a reply string B to send back
//char  sendY2[] = "Y2 = ";  // a reply string Z to send back
char  chX[9];  // a reply string X to send back
char  chY[9];  // a reply string Y to send back
char  chT[9];  // a reply string T to send back
char  chB[9];  // a reply string B to send back

float X,Y,T,B;
```

В Setup:

```
//Настройка и запуск Wi-Fi
Serial.printf("Connecting to %s ", ssid);
WiFi.begin(ssid, password);delay(7000);
if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
{
  delay(500);
  Serial.println("Not connected");}
  else {Serial.println(" connected");
  delay(1000);
  Udp.begin(localUdpPort);
  Serial.printf("Now listening at IP %s, UDP port %d\n", WiFi.localIP().toString().c_str(), localUdpPort);
  Serial.println(apIP);
}
```

В "Loop":

```
   X = accXangle;
   Y = accYangle;
   T = temp;
   B = volt;
floatTochar();// Переводим переменные в Char
  //Клиент ждет сообщение от сервера
  int packetSize = Udp.parsePacket();
  // Клиент отправляет сообщение первым!!!
    if (!packetSize){ 
   Udp.beginPacket(apIP, 4210);
   Udp.write(sendX);  //cначало посылаем маркер "X = " 
   Udp.write(chX);    // затем данные с оси X в char   
   Udp.endPacket();
    delay(25);
     Udp.beginPacket(apIP, 4210);//повторяем для оси Y
     Udp.write(sendY);
     Udp.write(chY); 
     Udp.endPacket();
     delay(25);
      Udp.beginPacket(apIP, 4210);
      Udp.write(sendT);
      Udp.write(chT); 
      Udp.endPacket();
       delay(25);
        Udp.beginPacket(apIP, 4210);
        Udp.write(sendB);
        Udp.write(chB); 
        Udp.endPacket();

// Функция перевода переменных в Char для возможности передачи по Wi-Fi
void floatTochar(){
  String strX;
  String strY;
  String strT;
    String strB;
  strX=String(X,3); // 3 знака после запятой
  strY=String(Y,3);
  strT=String(T,3);
  strB=String(B,3);
strX.toCharArray(chX,9);
strY.toCharArray(chY,9);
strT.toCharArray(chT,9);
strB.toCharArray(chB,9);
//char(X);
 // Serial.print(chX);Serial.print(" "); 
  //  Serial.print(chY);Serial.print(" "); 
   //  Serial.println(chT); 
}
```

На стороне приемника (сервер)

В "шапке"

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
IPAddress apIP(192,168,0,10);
IPAddress gateway(192,168,0,10);
IPAddress subnet(255,255,255,0);
const char* ssid = "Serv1";
const char* passwordе = "";
WiFiUDP Udp;

void setup()
{
  StartAPMode();

  Serial.println("AP Mode Activated");
  Serial.println( IPAddress(192, 168, 0, 10));

  Udp.begin(localUdpPort);
  delay(10000);
  Serial.printf("Now Streaming at IP %s, UDP port %d\n", WiFi.localIP().toString().c_str(), localUdpPort);
delay(1000);
}

void loop()
{     
  int packetSize = Udp.parsePacket();delay(autodelay);
  if (packetSize)
  { // receive incoming UDP packets
   // Serial.printf("Received %d bytes from %s, port %d\n", packetSize, Udp.remoteIP().toString().c_str(), Udp.remotePort());
    int len = Udp.read(incomingXYZ, 255);
    if (len > 0)
    {con=0; incomingXYZ[len] = 0;}
   // Serial.printf("UDP packet contents: %s\n", incomingXYZ);
     DataRead(data); 

  delay(autodelay); 
}

void DataRead(String &data)
{

  data = incomingXYZ;
  if (data.startsWith("X = ")){data=data.substring(4);
    X = data.toFloat(); 
    Serial.print("X = ");
    Serial.print(X,3);
    }
      else if (data.startsWith("Y = ")){data=data.substring(4);
    Y = data.toFloat(); 
    Serial.print(" Y = ");
    Serial.print(Y,3);}
      else if (data.startsWith("T = ")){data=data.substring(4);
      T = data.toFloat();   
      Serial.print(" Temp = ");
      Serial.print(T,3);}
         else if (data.startsWith("B =")){data=data.substring(4);
         B = data.toFloat()+0.1;  conry2=0;   
         Serial.print(" B = ");
         Serial.println(B,2);}  
}

bool StartAPMode()
{
  WiFi.disconnect();
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
  WiFi.softAPConfig(apIP, apIP, subnet);
  WiFi.softAP(ssid);
  delay(3000);
  return true;
}
```

Пояснения:

- клиент и сервер запускают UDP соединение;
- клиент получает данные с акселерометра и переводит их в Char;
- клиент формирует пакет с данными Char в виде "X = 75,123" и отправляет на сервер;
- если сервер принимает "X =" он сохраняет в буфер данные следующие за "X = " до конца строки;
- не дожидаясь ответа клиент отправляет данные типа "Y = 0,123";
- если сервер принимает "Y =" он сохраняет в буфер данные следующие за "Y = " до конца строки;
- сервер преобразует данные буфера в значения акселерометра (75,123, 0,123  и т.д.).